# code gives out ASCII numbers instead of characters

Tags: c++, char, ascii, red-black-tree

This code is part of a RedBlack Tree program supposed to receive "ADSOMERT" and sort its characters into Inorder form "A D E M O R S T". It does the job, but with the ASCII numbers of each character "65 68 69 77 79 82 83 84".

Main function:

```
int main()
{

    Tree char_tree = Tree();

    cout << "Eingabe: ADSOMERT" << endl;

    char_tree.insert('A');
    char_tree.insert('D');
    char_tree.insert('S');
    char_tree.insert('O');
    char_tree.insert('M');
    char_tree.insert('E');
    char_tree.insert('R');
    char_tree.insert('T');

    cout << "ADSOMERT in In-Order" << endl;

    char_tree.print_inorder();
}
```

insert and rb_insert fucntions:

```
void Tree::insert(int x)
{
    ...
}

void Tree::rb_insert(Node *& node, Node *&parent, int x, bool sw)
{
    ...
}
```

inorder and print_inorder functions:

```
void Tree::print_inorder()
{
    inorder(head->right);
    cout << endl;
}


void Tree::inorder(Knote* node)
{
    if (node != nullptr)
    {
        inorder(node->left);
        cout << node->item << " ";
        inorder(node->right);
    }
}
```

class dependencies for Node and Tree:

Node.h

```
class Node {
public:
    Node(int data = 0);
    bool red;
    int item;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    Node *parent;
};
```

Node.cpp

```
Node::Node(int data)
{
    this->item = data;

    parent = nullptr;
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
    red = true;
}
```

Comment: Your `insert` takes an `int` instead of a `char` what did you expect?

Comment: i made a new `insert(char x)` with a new `Node(char data)`, but nothing changed...

Comment: Please try to keep in mind you don't have to post all your code. Here's a [good guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) What you should post is the print_inorder function

Comment: ok I will edit the post now...

Comment: As Kyho has pointed out your data member type is an `int` also so you get a type conversion even if your params are `char`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Tree::inorder(Knote* node)
{
    if (node != nullptr)
    {
        inorder(node->left);
        cout << node->item << " ";
        inorder(node->right);
    }
}

class Node {
public:
    Node(int data = 0);
    bool red;
    int item;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    Node *parent;
};
```

You are outputting node->item and it is an int. Should be a char if you want to output "A D E M O R S T"

```
template <class T>
class Node{
public:
    Node(int data = 0);
    bool red;
    T item;
    ....
};
```

Something like this

Comment: thanks the `item` was the problem not the `data`. how can i define `item` as a `char` type and `integer` at the same time? since the main purpose of the program is to work with numbers and the ADSOMERT thing is just an intro...

Comment: You can try making it a template class if you intend to use various data types.

Comment: by adding a `template` before class and redefining `item` as `char`?